# Passing id in a custom column in a webgrid is throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a simple MVC3 application in which I am using WebGrid control to display list of Employees.

My models are :

```
public class EmployeeList
{
    public List<Employee> ListOfEmployees { get; set; }
}


public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And EmployeeList.cshtml is as follows:

```
@model test.Models.EmployeeList
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListOfEmployees";
    WebGrid grid = null;
    if (Model != null)
    {
        grid = new WebGrid(Model.ListOfEmployees);
    }
}

<h2>Employee List is as follows:</h2>
@if (Model == null)
{
    <p>Their is no Employee Data in database.</p>
}
else
{
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    alternatingRowStyle:"alt",
    columns: new[]{
    grid.Column("Id", header: "Employee Id", canSort: true),
    grid.Column("Name", header: "Employee Name"),
    grid.Column("", header:"Action", format: (item) =>   @Html.ActionLink("Delete","Home", new { }))
    })
}
```

As it can be seen in last custom column, I am trying to create a Delete link for every record.
But I am not able to pass Id , because the moment I write "id" inside new{}, VS throws error : "The name 'id' does not exist in current context".

Why is this error coming up, am I missing something...Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
format: (item) = >
{
var links = Html.ActionLink("Delete", "ActionName","ControllerName", new {id = item.PrimaryKey},null) 
return Html.Raw(links.ToString())
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. The only thing I had to write was links.toString() otherwise it was giving invalid arguements error. So what was missing in my code, could you please tell me? @Shujaat

Comment: moreover i would recommend you to use jqgrid instead of webgrid

Comment: you missed few things. first your actionlink method was not properly defined. and second Html.Raw Methods as it return to the HTML String.